# Libharu explain link in QT c++

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, lib, libharu

I download **libharu.zip**, try to include it into QT creator c++.
But I don't have lib*.a files in **libharu**. What do I need to do? It has some makefiles etc.

I find some info about makefile, but don`t understand how it works in QT creator.

`nmake -f Makefile.win`

What do I need to run this command?

Comment: You have to build the library. Do you use CMake or qmake?

Comment: How can I build it? I don't find any explanation on their site documentation

Comment: https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Installation

Answer (score -1):

You will **need a .so or a .a** for linking, in qt creator edit your .pro:

```
INCLUDEPATH     += <path_to_lib>/your_lib_include
```

When you have a .so for linking:

```
LIBS += -L<path_to_lib> -l<libname>
```

When you have a .a  for linking:

```
LIBS += <path_to_lib>/libname.a
```

Comment: I don`t have .a or .so in downloaded zip, this is the problem, I don't know how to compile makefile on windows(or any system)

Comment: @Usagi You have to build it https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Installation. As far as I saw there are no prebuilt libraries.

Comment: I found where I need to type these commands and get this.
Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.6.2. And get this: NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'src\hpdf_utils.obj' Stop.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a more clear what you're trying to achieve, 
Quoting libharu: **"Haru can work as both a static-library (.a, .lib) and a shared-library (.so, .dll).**
So your question must be "How to compile libharu in windows and integrate with Qt"